# Вставка значений в цикл

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят подскажите - как вставить блок в цикл!
Тоесть выводит данные из бд в див и например после 5 дива нужно вставить текст

Comment: [Циклы вообще](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), [циклы в PHP](http://www.php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles). А вообще - сначала читать учебник, потом сюда ходить, если там что-то непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увеличение по 5,но думаю тебе нужно учится

```
for ($i=0; $i < ; $i+=5) { 
    # code...
}
```